# Newly created kotlin project gives gradle error despite changing gradle plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

[image]Errors

[image]

Hello Everyone,

I am receiving these errors and have been looking around over the internet for solution but none worked, can anyone please help me?
Android Studio is up to date 3.6
All SDKs are up to date
Kotlin Plugin is up to date 1.3.61

Comment: You may have checked Offline mode in settings , try to uncheck offline work

Comment: Yesterday, I updated Android Studio and since then at-least i can't find offline work, in Build, Execution and Deployment and Gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened the project in IntelliJ Idea, it took some time but downloaded all required files and now running with all functionalities without any other errors.